# Making a dictionary from a list

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I want to write a function that imports ascii_lowercase and returns a dictionary with the letters of keys as keys and a randomly shuffled version of the keys as values.

for example,

```
keys = "abcdefg..."
```

and then you shuffle it and get `gydwsk...` as an example, and the dictionary should look like

```
{'a':'g', 'b':'y', 'c':'d'...}
```

Im not sure where to begin, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shuffle it with `random.shuffle`. Here is an example:

```
import random

keys = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrdtuvxz'
shuffle_keys = list_keys = list(keys)

random.shuffle(shuffle_keys)

my_dict = dict(zip(keys, shuffle_keys))

print(my_dict)
```

**Edited**

Good suggestion for simpler dict construction (from comments. Thanks)

Comment: better to use `for k, s in zip(keys, shuffle_keys):`, also, it seems like `list_keys` isn't really useful...

Comment: or just `dict(zip(keys, shuffle_keys))`

Answer (score 1):

A one liner. You can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample) to avoid the in place reordering nature of [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle). Then combine the shuffled and non-shuffled values using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), which can be passed directly to the dict constructor to make the new dict.

The use of `alc` as a shortening for `ascii_lowercase` is for brevity in the example and is probably a bit too brutal a shortening for most production code.

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase as alc
>>> from random import sample
>>> dict(zip(alc, sample(alc, len(alc))))
{'b': 'a', 's': 'w', 'v': 'g', 'g': 'n', 'k': 'v', 'c': 'h', 'h': 'j', 'u': 'f', 'd': 'i', 'n': 'p', 'x': 'y', 'r': 'm', 't': 'u', 'o': 's', 'j': 'e', 'e': 'c', 'l': 'b', 'y': 'z', 'q': 'k', 'z': 'd', 'f': 't', 'p': 'r', 'm': 'l', 'i': 'o', 'w': 'x', 'a': 'q'}
```

You will not see them in alphabetical order, but this is expected from an unordered container.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def f(keys):
    shuffled = list(keys)
    random.shuffle(shuffled)
    return dict(zip(keys, shuffled))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work (python version < 3.0):

```
import random
keys="abcdefg"
dictionary = {}
shuffled = ''.join(random.sample(keys,len(keys)))
shuffled_iterator = 0
for letter in keys:
  dictionary[letter] = shuffled[shuffled_iterator]
  shuffled_iterator +=1

print dictionary
```